# Passing Bokeh plot objects into and out of functions

Tags: python, function, plot, bokeh

I am currently using Bokeh to make multiple plots and generating their components (script/div). I pass in the plot object to a function, add plot lines to the object based on calculations performed in the function, I then pass the object out to main. I do this frequently for different functions. This seems to create a drastic slowdown when running my program as compared to matplotlib - 12 minutes bokeh to 1 minute matplotlib.

I believe this may be due to the copying of values in and out of the function. Each plot object contains 4 plot line of about 5000 points each. There are at most 16 plots in the program.

Is there a better way to pass in/out the plot objects or should I plot all objects and formatting at the end of the program to minimize the overhead?

Answer (score 1):

There are unfortunate and unavoidable tensions between interactive, exploratory use-cases and development use-cases. Making Bokeh simple, convenient and unobtrusive to use in Jupyter Notebooks, etc. meant making it do some "automagic" things. In particular there is an implicit "current document", and unless it is explicitly cleared, *everything* that is created with higher level APIs accumulates there. Long story, short: For this kind of application you should explicitly clear the current document:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
curdoc().clear()
```

after you template/render a particular plot and are done with it (i.e. after you call `components`)

If you still ned to hold on to the plots longer than that, after you call `components`, then you will need to partially drop down to the lower level API and create your own documents explicitly. Most of the examples here demonstrate creating documents by hand:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/models

Comment: To be precise, I generate the components at the end, but the slowdown is when I am adding plots to the plot object in and out of functions. I am also generating static html files at the end of the program that do'nt require updating after they are generated. Is there a way to get around this? I am not familiar with curdoc.clear() and its use cases.

Comment: It's impossible to give more guidance without details and specifics, and mostly like, a reproducible test case. I'd suggest coming by the public mailing list which much more suited than SO to iterative and collaborative discussions.